# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have an error on login form after upgrading version Vue JS, Axios, Laravel.
This project code working well with old version. Anyone can explain this serious errors.
Thanks you for your help!
And I stuck with it many days. I've search for similar post error, but only seen this(POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)).

```
<template>
            <div class="back-img" :style="`background-image: url('${appUrl}/images/background/default-background.jpg')`">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-lg-4 offset-lg-8 col-xl-4 offset-xl-8 pl-0">
                            <div class="sign-in-sign-up-content">
                                <form class="sign-in-sign-up-form">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-4 application-logo">
                                        <img :src="publicPath+'/uploads/logo/'+appLogo" alt="" class="img-fluid logo">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                                            <h3 class="text-center mb-0">
                                                {{ trans('lang.hi_there') }}
                                            </h3><br>
                                            <label class="text-center d-block">
                                                {{ trans('lang.sign_in_to_your_dashboard') }}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-if="alertMessage.length>0" class="alertBranch">
                                        <div class="alert alert-warning alertBranch" role="alert">
                                            {{alertMessage}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div><br>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                                            <label for="username" style="font-size: 20px;"> {{ trans('lang.login_username') }}</label>
                                            <input id="username"
                                                   v-validate="'required'"
                                                   v-model="username"
                                                   type="text"
                                                   name="username"
                                                   class="form-control"
                                                   :placeholder="trans('lang.enter_username')"
                                                   :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('username') }">
                                            <div class="heightError" v-if="submitted && errors.has('username')">
                                                <small class="text-danger" v-show="errors.has('username')">
                                                    {{ errors.first('username') }}
                                                </small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                                            <label for="password" style="font-size: 20px !important;">{{ trans('lang.login_password') }}</label>
                                            <input id="password"
                                                   v-validate="'required'"
                                                   ref="password"
                                                   v-model="password"
                                                   name="password"
                                                   type="password"
                                                   class="form-control"
                                                   :placeholder="trans('lang.enter_password')"
                                                   :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('password') }">
                                            <div class="heightError">
                                                <small class="text-danger" v-show="errors.has('password')">
                                                    {{ errors.first('password') }}
                                                </small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row loginButton">
                                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                                            <common-submit-button class="btn-block text-center auth-button"
                                                                  style="font-size: 20px !important;"
                                                                  :buttonLoader="buttonLoader"
                                                                  :isDisabled="isDisabled"
                                                                  :isActiveText="isActiveText"
                                                                  buttonText="login"
                                                                  v-on:submit="loginPost"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                                            <a href="#"
                                               @click="forgetPassword"
                                               class="bluish-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock"/>
                                                {{ trans('lang.forgot_password') }}
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> -->
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

<script>

    import axiosGetPost from '../../helper/axiosGetPostCommon';
    export default {
        extends: axiosGetPost,
        props: ['checkusername', 'checkpass'],
        data() {
            return {
                username: this.checkusername,
                name: '',
                password: this.checkpass,
                remember: true,
                buttonLoader: false,
                isActiveText: false,
                isDisabled: false,
                preLoaderType: 'load',
                hidePreLoader: false,
                isActive: 'active',
                alertMessage: '',
                submitted: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loginPost() {
                this.submitted = true,
                    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            this.inputFields = {
                                username: this.username,
                                password: this.password,
                            };
                            this.buttonLoader = true;
                            this.isDisabled = true;
                            this.isActiveText = true;
                            this.loginPostMethod('/', {
                                    username: this.username,
                                    password: this.password,
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    });
            },
            forgetPassword() {
                let instance = this;
                instance.redirect('/password/reset');
            },
            loginPostSucces(response) {
                let instance = this;
                instance.redirect("/sales");
            },
            loginPostError(response) {
                let instance = this;
                instance.buttonLoader = false;
                instance.isDisabled = false;
                instance.isActiveText = false;
                instance.alertMessage = response.data.errors.username[0];
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

File: resources\assets\js\js\bootstrap.js

```
    window._ = require('lodash');
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    import axios from "axios";
    
    try {
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    
        require('bootstrap');
    } catch (e) {}
    
    window.axios = require('axios');
    
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    if (document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')) {
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    }
```

Comment: CSRF token is missing from header

Comment: Already have in : resources\views\layouts\include\head.blade.php 
  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the csrf token in Ajax request.

```
data: {
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    other form data
}
```

**OR**

You can create csrf token in header using meta element and access that value in while sending ajax request.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

// Access in ajax request like below

headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Laravel + Vue + Axios
Laravel has configurd the default token header in `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

So you have to just import axios like.

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: Already try, but still the same.

Comment: If you are using laravel + vue js + axios then you must have axios common header configured by defualt by laravel. You just have to import axios instance in vue file you wanted to post or get any data.

Comment: ! yes brother, My code contain the code details that you give. But still error. You can see it above in (resources\assets\js\js\bootstrap.js).